# Zend Optimizer+ error

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

Can an anyone help me.I am getting the following error while running my drupal 7 application

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function views_views_plugins() (previously declared in /var/www/vhosts/cibi.hq.k.grp/newsite/sites/all/modules/views/includes/plugins.inc:15). If this code worked without the Zend Optimizer+, please set zend_optimizerplus.dups_fix=1 in your ini file in /var/www/vhosts/cibi.hq.k.grp/newsite/sites/all/modules/ctools/ctools.module on line 113

Comment: Did you notice this part of the error message:  If this code worked without the Zend Optimizer+, please set zend_optimizerplus.dups_fix=1 in your ini file

Comment: FWIW, I don't have zend_optimizerplus.dups_fix=1 set on any of y servers running Drupal 7 with views.  Clear your cache.  I think your registry may be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The very same thing happened to me after transferring my website to another hosting company.

**You must run update.php.**

Since I was logged out, the way I resolved this is as follows: I typed in the url box www.example.com/update.php (www.example.com being your site's name. If it's on your local machine, I guess it is something like localhost/update.php.)

If your settings.php file is properly configured, you should get an access denied message.

In that case, go to the directory (sites/default) and open the settings.php file. Look for the line *$update_free_access = FALSE;* and change it to TRUE.

Run update.php again. You will find a link at the bottom of the result page sending you to the front page. Click on it and your site is back in business. :)

CAUTION. Very important: Go to your settings.php file again and change the TRUE back to FALSE.